# How to display uploaded images?

Tags: oracle, coldfusion

I have successfully uploaded some images to the server. My problem is I don't know how to retrieve the images. How can I display uploaded images on my server?

I am thinking I would like to create a Word document which will display those images. Can any help?

```
    <!--- Set Directory Name --->
    <cfset dirName  = Mid(noFailPemohon,17,7)>
    <cfset variables.namaGambar1 = '' />
    <cfset variables.namaGambar2 = '' />

    <!--- Parameter --->
    <cfparam name="filePath" default="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SPPV2\03_Teknikal\upload\#dirName#\">
    <cfparam name="filePath2" default="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SPPV2\03_Teknikal\upload\PelanRumah\">

    <!--- Create Dir If Not Exist --->
    <cfif not DirectoryExists('C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SPPV2\03_Teknikal\upload\#dirName#\')>
        <cfdirectory directory= "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SPPV2\03_Teknikal\upload\#dirName#\" action="create">
    </cfif>

    <cfif not DirectoryExists('C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SPPV2\03_Teknikal\upload\PelanRumah\')>
        <cfdirectory directory= "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SPPV2\03_Teknikal\upload\PelanRumah\" action="create">
    </cfif>

    <!--- Upload Gambar1 --->
    <cfif isDefined("Form.gambar1")>
        <cftry>
            <!--- Upload To Server --->
            <cffile action="upload" 
                filefield="Form.gambar1" 
                destination="#filePath#" 
                nameconflict="overwrite" 
                result="status">

            <!--- Rename File --->
            <cftry>
                <cffile action="rename" 
                    source="#filePath##status.clientFile#" 
                    destination="#filePath#GambarLaporan#VISIT_NUMBER#.#status.clientFileExt#">

                <cfcatch type="any">
                </cfcatch>
            </cftry>

            <cfcatch type="any"></cfcatch>
        </cftry>
        <cfset variables.namaGambar1 = "#status.serverdirectory#\#status.serverfile#" >
    </cfif>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you included `oracle` in the tags? Are you saving the file path in a database? Also do not "swallow" errors like this: `<cfcatch type="any"></cfcatch>`.

Answer (score 3):

why can't you just use a standard HTML `<img>` tag to display the file? You know where the destination file is already.

```
<img src="https://yourwebsite.com/#filePath#GambarLaporan#VISIT_NUMBER#.#status.clientFileExt#">
```

You may need to replace `\` with `/` for your url, but it should be as simple as that.

UPDATE: If you're showing the image on another page you need to pass that value to the new page.

```
<cfset ImageLocation = "#filePath#GambarLaporan#VISIT_NUMBER#.#status.clientFileExt#">
<cflocation url="mypage.cfm?Image=#url.ImageLocation#" addtoken="false">
```

Comment: i have tried that. but then there's an error.


Element CLIENTFILEEXT is undefined in STATUS

i am planning to display the images in a different page. not in the same coding page.

Comment: if you're displaying the image on a different page are you passing in the `status.clientFileExt` name? If not that's your issue. I updated my answer with some more information.

Comment: dear matt, i passed the status.clientFileExt but still the same error occurs. or did i missing something here?

Comment: how are you passing it? If you're setting it to a new variable you need to reference that variable.

Comment: i have edited my full program. in case you want to view it. thanks.

Comment: @faz i'm not seeing where you're trying to display the image